# How can I develop a script (Python, Bash, etc.) to know if a website has Angular?

Tags: web-scraping, console

I would like to develop a script in any programming language to detect if a website uses Angular and version. Something like the following:

Example of what the script would look like:

```
./versionAngular.py -t https://www.website.com

> Detect version Angular in Website....
> Website https://www.website.com has Angular, version 1.4.7
```

I know that I can detect it with the Browser Console by writing `angular.version`, however I would like to create a script to be able to do this myself through the Unix Console, is it understood?

Comment: can you be more specific?  I am trying to understand your question but I am having a hard time understanding what you are looking for.

Comment: Your question is too broad. I guess I understand what you want: you want to create a program in any language that will call angular.version and return it in some way. But that's not a question, it's a whole task.

Comment: What I specifically need is to create a script that will pass as a website parameter and tell me if the website is using Angular or not, that's basically it.

I made reference to the Browser console since it is enough to write angular.version to know if the site uses or not Angular depending on what it returns.

Thanks

Comment: I added some basic formatting to your question, but I think you still need to [edit] it and clarify your question.

Comment: Now if I have formalized the question again, I hope it will be understood, thank you very much.